# Woocommerce add_filter to hide a flat rate method at certain times and not able to var_dump variable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Completely new to Woocommerce/wordpress here. On the cart page `mydomain.local/cart` What filter should I use to show/hide a flat rate shipping method at certain times. From admin I managed to add an extra flat rate method and named it "Next day". Now I would like to show that flat rate method only before 4PM. I tried in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_change_shipping', 10);

function custom_change_shipping($rates) {
    var_dump($rates);
}
```

Nothing seems to change and also I cant seem to debug the `$rates` variable as nothing is outputted when `var_dump($rates);`. I tried it both anonymous and as an admin but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Thank you, I thought this could be the right filter. And also I found a way to output my var_dump that I was having trouble with and I will be posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @LoicTheAztec for confirming whether I was using the right filter. My other problem was that I was not able to output `var_dump` on the `/cart` page.

I found out that I need to clear my "cart cache" by going to woocommerce->settings->shipping and in the region, disable then enable again and click on save changes. 
By doing this I could see my output from `var_dump`.

Comment: I'm trying to do this exact thing but I can't see @LoicTheAztec's comment/answer. What was the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Filter posted earlier by @LoicTheAztec (as requested by @robert)

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_hide_shipping', 100 );
    function custom_hide_shipping( $rates ) {

    $current_time = date_i18n(('H'), current_time('timestamp')); //Uses Timezone Settings > General
    $maximum_time = array (
        'time' =>'16'); //4PM

    if ($current_time >= $maximum['time']){
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:X'] ); // change X to your rate id
        }
        return $rates;
    }
```